# SQL Server to Oracle Migration Cannot Find User

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, migration

I migrated a SQL Server database to Oracle 11 Express and have trouble to connect to the converted database in Oracle SQL Developer. I followed the instruction here: [Oracle Migration](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/mssqlserver/migrate_microsoft_sqlserver_otn.htm) the only difference is I am using an on-line migration.

I have successfully converted the database, but what I am struggling with is I cannot connect to the converted database because there is no user migrated (or created). Please see image below. I wonder if anyone has the same problem before or can give me directions how to solve this.

much appreciated for any suggestions/helps.

[image]

Comment: We have a series of short videos to talk you through the process here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/sqlserver-095136.html Your migration project should show what's going on, what steps you've completed, etc. TR_TEST is your schema. Connect as TR_TEST.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I've followed the video, but i am still not able to connect TR_TEST, what is the default password how come i cannot find the user under Converted Database?

Comment: probably easier to continue this conversation over a different forum? jeff.d.smith@oracle.com

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server to Oracle Migration - connect migrated user

1. If your migration is completed and your repository has recorded all migration transactions.
2. It is confirmed that before migration you created Oracle User. you are well aware about the password.
3. If you have lost after migration.
4. Just log in as System or Sysdba user and change the particular username password. That's it.
5. Now connect to migrated user.